# Status bar only show battery in iOS7 when UIImagePickerController pop

Tags: ios7, statusbar

When UIImagePickerController push,I make the status bar hidden.And when the UIImagePickerController pop,I make the status bar show,but at the point the status bar only show the battery as the screenshot.
[image]

When I jump to anther ViewController,the status bar recover normally.
How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I just had the exact same problem. In my case the background image of the navigation controller was of 44px height instead of the required 64px for iOS 7.

Also had to make sure to remove:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
```

After that it all worked perfectly.

If you need a temporary workaround in case you don't have a navigation bar background of the required size yet you can use the following on your VC `viewDidAppear`:

```
[self.navigationController setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];
```